# Bathroom sink decorative cap removal

Tags: bathroom, faucet

Anyone know how to get a cap or handle like this off?  No screws, no place to pry cap off, it doesn’t turn.[image]

Comment: If it's glued down you might have luck heating it up before trying to twist it off. But it looks like a pretty big heat sink.

Comment: I have had that type that had a set screw on the side to hold it in place look there first. (On the shaft)

Answer (score 1):

It could be pressed into some plumber's putty. Use pieces of duct tape to make a full contact "wing nut" to grab the dome. Then drip some baby oil around the groove. Use the wing nut to try to wiggle and lift, and add some more drops of baby oil. Do not pry with anything or you might chip the porcelain dome.